# Loading sounds with loadCompressedDataFromByteArray and play them later?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, air

I'm trying to load mp3 files with **loadCompressedDataFromByteArray()** and then play them later but there seems to be no means to do that. When loading with loadCompressedDataFromByteArray the Sound class only dispatches the ID3 event and none of the other events (complete, open, etc.). If I just load the sound with loadCompressedDataFromByteArray and then at some later point try to play the sound I get:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063
```

The only option right now seems to start playing the sound right after a call to loadCompressedDataFromByteArray() ...

```
_sound.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray(_bytes, _bytes.length); 
_sound.play();
```

But that completely useless in my case as I'm trying to preload mp3 files that need to be used later.

Anyone know any workaround for this?

Comment: full error messages are always helpful.

Comment: Could this be related to this? "The data will be read from the current ByteArray position and will leave the ByteArray position at the end of the specified bytes length once finished" (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#loadCompressedDataFromByteArray%28%29)

Comment: Nope, I've set the ByteArray position to zero before loading it into the sound. However it dimmed to me by now that this is actually a totally broken API. A completely miserable job done by Adobe! The same applies to the other newly added sound method loadPCMFromByteArray() which is also broken, see here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASL-281 (and please vote). I would file a bug about the loadCompressedDataFromByteArray method too, if only Adobe's Bug system would let me register (seems to be broken too :-/).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error and by setting the byteArray position to 0 before calling `loadCompressedDataFromByteArray` fixed it for me:

```
_bytes.position = 0;
_sound.loadCompressedDataFromByteArray(_bytes, _bytes.length); 
_sound.play();
```

Does that answer your question?